# Nest Js + Prisma, authentication error for mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nestjs, prisma

I am getting the following authentication error while running `npx prisma db push` command in terminal for NestJs+Prisma project

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MongoDB database "test" at "localhost:27017"
Error: MongoDB error
SCRAM failure: Authentication failed.
   0: schema_core::commands::schema_push::Calculate `from`
             at schema-engine/core/src/commands/schema_push.rs:29
   1: schema_core::state::SchemaPush
             at schema-engine/core/src/state.rs:432
```

I am using Prisma to connect with mongodb using this code

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}


model User {
  id                  String       @id @default(uuid()) @map("_id")
  createdAt           DateTime     @default(now())
  updatedAt           DateTime     @updatedAt
  emailId             String
  @@index([emailID])
}
```

And my database string in `.env` file is

```
// DB Name is test
DATABASE_URL="mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/test?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"
```

I am using the following version of Prisma & Prisma-Client

```
"@prisma/client": "^5.0.0",
"prisma": "^5.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `authSource=admin` to the URL params.
So the new URL would be like:

```
mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/test?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
```